# Yaos Millionaire Problem: Why distance >= 2?

Tags: protocol-design, oblivious-transfer

I'm  currently reading about Yao' Millionaire Problem: http://research.cs.wisc.edu/areas/sec/yao1982-ocr.pdf

Alice and Bob want to know which of them is richer.
Let $j \in \{1, \cdots 10\}$ be Bobs fortune, and $i$ Alice's.
They share a public-private key pair where $E_A$ is the encryption with Alice's public key and $D_A$ the corresponding decryption function.

Here is Yao's roadmap:

1. Bob picks a random $N$-bit integer $x$, and computes privately the value of $E_A(x)$; call the result $k$.
2. Bob sends Alice the number $k-j+ 1$.
3. Alice computes privately the values of $y_u=D_A(k-j+u)$ for $u= 1,2, \cdots,10$.
4. Alice generates a random prime $p$ of $N/2$ bits, and computes the values $z_u=y_u \mod p$ for all $u$ ; 
   if all $z_u$ differ by at least 2 in the $\bmod p$ sense, stop;
   otherwise generates another random prime and repeat the process until all $z_u$ differ by at least 2 ; 
   let $p, z_u$ denote this final set of numbers.
5. Alice sends the prime $p$ and the following 10 numbers to Bob:
   $z_1, z_2, \cdots , z_i$ followed by $z_{i}+ 1, z_{i+1}+1 , \cdots , z_{10}+ 1$
   the above numbers should be interpreted in the $\bmod p$ sense.
6. Bob looks at the $j$-th number (not counting $p$ ) sent from Alice, and decides that $i \ge j$ if it is equal to $x \bmod p$,  and $i < j$ otherwise.

I understand everything, but I'm at loss at step 4.
Why do the $z_u$ have to differ by at least 2?
What can Bob deduce from Alice's List, if that condition is not fulfilled?

Added 8.5.16:
I found that Bruce Schneier mentions that protocol in  "Applied Cryptography".
He writes:
"All the verification ... is to guarantee that no number appears twice in the sequence ... Otherwise, if $z_a = z_b$, Alice knows that $a \le j < b$'' (Schneier interchanged Alice and Bob and $i$ with $j$). But he does not explain, why the initiator of the protocol can deduce that.

One more idea: Maybe the condition is not needed for all asymmetric encryption schemes but only for RSA (the only one at that time?). But I cannot show that either.

Added 9.6.16

One more thought:
Let's assume, Bob gets from Alice a list that looks like:
[$w_i$] = [11,7,6,22,33,44,55,66,77,88], then he can argue as follows:

1. Opps, the list contains two elements having distance one (7,6)
2. Alice follows the protocol, so the $z_i$ differ by at least 2
3. So Alice, when calculating the $w_i$ must have incremented the smaller one of the corresponding $z$s
4. So [$z_i$] must have been [11,7,5,21,32,43,54,65,76,87]
5. So Alice's fortune equals 2

So I think, the distance condition is not only useless but dangerous because it removes entropy from the result set (and adds information).

Comment: Welcome to crypto-SE. A quick note, tho: If you use the latex math formulas (see [markdown](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/editing-help)), formulas are much more readable. And you should try to have all the necessary information in your post, e.g. "$E_A$ denotes encryption with Alice public key" (which wasn't obvious on the first glance; and after checking the paper, that is just in the paragraph before your quotation).

Comment: Ups. While reading my posting again, I found, that I cited it correctly from Yao, but I think, there's a mistake in Step 5. It Must be '': ... and the following 10 numbers to B: $z_1, z_2 \cdots,z_i$ followed by $z_{i+1}+1 \cdots, ,z_{10}+1$ ...''  ($z_i$ not duplicated).

Comment: I'm not familiar with this protocol, but looking at step 5, it seems likely that the reason why the $z$ values must differ by at least two is to avoid the possibility that $z_a = z_b+1$ for some $a$ and $b$, which could cause two of the numbers transmitted in step 5 to be identical. I'm not sure why that would actually be a problem, though.

Comment: Wow, this protocol is ancient. Yao is famous for solving the Millionaire's problem using Yao's Garbled Circuits. He did this in 1986. This protocol is 4 years before that. I wonder though, why do you spend time on this protocol? Is this an assignment or you do it because you want to learn everything about Yao?

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen: It seems you are right, at least that is what Bruce Schneier writes. But I still do not see, how this would be a problem.

Comment: @Aventinus: No, its not a homework. I'm only trying (and still failing) to understand that step in the protocol. Yeah i'ts really ancient, but cool.

Comment: I would recommend against spending much time studying Yao's Millionaires' Problem, and especially Yao's original solution, which is mostly of historical interest.

Comment: On February 8, 2020 I had the exact same question, and its good to see that im not the only one mystified by this